# Tensorflow py_func TypeError with tf.data.Dataset output

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to return a dataset from a function using py_func for use in the tensorflow Dataset pipeline/api. However, py_func throws an error:

```
TypeError: Expected DataType for argument 'Tout' not <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.Dataset'>.
```

A minimal example is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def fn(x, y):
    a = tf.data.Dataset_from_tensors((x, y))
    b = tf.data.Dataset_from_tensors((x, y))
    return a.concatenate(b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    features = np.random.rand(5, 5, 5, 1)
    labels = np.random.rand(5, 5)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((features, labels))
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(
        lambda feature, label:  tuple(tf.py_func(
            fn, [feature, label], [tf.data.Dataset])))
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    sess = tf.Session()
    val = sess.run(next_element)
```

Is this a bug with tensorflow, or am I using the api incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using it wrongly. `Tout: A list or tuple of tensorflow data types or a single tensorflow data type if there is only one, indicating what func returns.`

Comment: If you are indicating that it should be ` tf.data.Dataset`  rather than `[tf.data.Dataset]`, both report the same error, otherwise I guess I am misunderstanding what you are saying. Is tf.data.Dataset not a `tensorflow data type`, as it is my understanding that is what fn should be returning.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.py_func` enables us to wrap python code when the equivalent Tensorflow API is not easily available.

*I think it cannot return Tensorflow classes.*

As an example I've copied this code which I posted in another thread. This code uses the Python API to format dates that are read from a file. And the returned datatype is a Tensorflow datatype.

`tf.py_func` is convenient to include seamlessly in the data pipeline subject to the limitations mentioned in the [API doc.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime


sess = tf.Session()

#Could be refactored
def convert_to_date(text):
    date = datetime.strptime(text.decode('ascii'), '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
    return date.strftime('%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')

filenames = ["C:/Machine Learning/text.txt"]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

tf.data.TextLineDataset
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
                   lambda filename :
                   tf.data.TextLineDataset( filename ) ).map( lambda text :
                                                                        tf.py_func(convert_to_date,
                                                                                  [text],
                                                                                  [tf.string]))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
date = iterator.get_next()


print(sess.run([date]))
```